# Predefined stucture for a webgis-application with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I would like to know if different "typical WEBGIS-desgins" for OpenLayers exist (e.g. html-structures),
e.g. something like a well designed layer-selection (better than that, I show in the picture), a place for the legend,
a wms-loader and and and...

[image: Not very well designed layer selection]

Could anybody help?

Thank you very much, Kai

Answer (score 1):

Here [http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/) you can find some nice extensions.

Comment: Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Might it be that ol-ext does not work in OL5? Only in OL3 or OL4?

Comment: I use the extensions in an older version even under OL5. The current release 3.1.7 is - if I understand it right - tailored to OL6. Therefore, you will probably either have to use OL6 or even modify the code for OL5. It's best to contact Jean-Marc Viglino directly.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, OL5 works nice with ol-ext.
Its necessary e.g. to do a "npm install openlayers-ext".

And then the modules can be implemented like

```
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import ol_control_Print from 'ol-ext/control/Print'
import Select from 'ol/interaction/Select'
import ol_control_Legend from 'ol-ext/control/Legend'
```